Ubuntu with desktop environment vs. Ubuntu flavour
May be this is a silly question, but I was not able to find a proper answer yet.
So, what is the difference between installing a given Ubuntu flavour or installing the normal Ubuntu and then put the desired desktop environment on top of it?
For example, is it better to install Ubuntu Budgie or install Ubuntu and then put the Budgie desktop in it? Or install Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu + KDE Plasma? Etc.
I presume that it should not be the same, otherwise there would not be any reason for having so many flavours, am I right?

It can be identical, or different - depending on what you install.  Years ago when I started using Ubuntu I always downloaded and installed Ubuntu Desktop as that ISO my ISP allowed me to have quota free, I could then switch to use the ISP's mirror & switch packages myself again bandwidth quota free; so I went that route as it prevented me reaching my quota and having my line drop to dial up speeds last couple of days in the month. Many users however install desktops directly & not the tweaks provided by flavor teams - so results vary on how installed (desktop? or flavor meta-packages)

You can look up what exactly goes on a flavor ISO via their seed, contrast all flavors and Ubuntu Desktop/Server as they're all found at the same place on launchpad.... or just contrast the manifest files too if you want to look at the packages found on ISO (rather that seed file that causes that to occur).  You can then see what metapackages they install, and contrast with what many users on this & other sites install when they grab desktops only (or do your own explore)

https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/kubuntu.noble/desktop  is the Kubuntu NOBLE (24.04) seed...  you can explore there and contrast with other flavors or Ubuntu (desktop/server) team files. All are built by the same builders & managed by same Ubuntu Release Team in same manner...  if you use the same packages you'll get identical results; but many people don't add additional desktops using flavor meta-packages (using packages that may have been sourced from upstream Debian sid) thus get similar but not identical.
